# list with text on both left and right side of each item? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

i'd like to start by saying that im quite new to android developing.

my question is how can i change my below examples to allow text on both the left and right side of each list item.

my aim is to have each list item have an item description on the left, and a numeric value for that description on the right.

all i have up to now is a list that shows the values which i want showing on the left of each item.

main java activity (NewtestActivity.java):

```
public class NewtestActivity extends Activity {
    String[] exampleList = {
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Test 4",
        "Item 5",
        "Test 6",
        "Item 7",
        "Test 8"
        //etc etc
    };

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get an instance of your listview in code
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Set the listview's adapter       
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exampleList));
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for any help (:

Comment: You should have to use custom ListView. Following are some usefull link:
http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extend ArrayAdapter
2. Edit android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to contain the layout you
   want

[Check this example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply and example.. but how can i change that example so that i would be able to display the elements from R.layout.main as well as the list, without it crashing?

Comment: check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928002/help-with-listview-and-r-layout-main-android/6928142#6928142

Answer (score 2):

With no direct link to your question, you can improve your xml code and your first `LinearLayout` (header), by using the attribute `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawablePadding` of your `TextView`.

This accords you to place your icon on the left of your appName TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Define Custom Adapter like this and define your custum layout xml file as per your need.

```
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private Vector mValuestobeShown;
    private Vector mValuetext;
        private Vector mValueNumber; 

    public YourAdapter (Context context, Vector text,Vector item, Vector number){
        mContext = context;
                mValuetext = text;
                mValuestobeShown = item;
        mValueNumber = number;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if(null != mValuestobeShown){
            return mValuestobeShown.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if(position < mValuestobeShown.size())
            return  mValuestobeShown.get(position);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder ;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                        holder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.num);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try{
            holder.item.setText(mValueType.get(position).toString());
            //set other values.....
        }catch(Exception e){  }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
                TextView item;
        TextView num;

    }

}
```