# help with listview and R.layout.main (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

im quite new to android, so i apologise if this is a noob-ish question (:

i designed my list following the example found here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html

but what i would like to know is how would i go about adding setContentView(R.layout.main) so that i can display other (xml) elements along with the list?

thanks for any advice (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just edit your main.xml to look whatever you want it to look, eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <View android:id="@+id/emptyview"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  />
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/emptyview"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change your activity to extend only Activity, not ListActivity. Finally, in your activity you can then fetch your list view with:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

and do whatever you need to do with the list.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion (:  ..but when i tried it, i got a force close :/   any ideas?

Comment: ..working now, weirdly. everything was fine with the code, i just reinstalled and restarted the app then it was fine (:

Comment: eclipse does that sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You create your main.xml
2. Add to it a ListView

   ```
   <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/myListView"
   android:divider="#ffa500" android:dividerHeight="1px"
   android:background="@drawable/somedrawable_xml"        
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ListView>
   ```

`somedrawable_xml.xml` could be any drawable example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#00ffa500" />
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffa500" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
```

Add a layout xmlFile `myLayout.xml` example: (I added imageView for demonstration) anyway what is important is the id of the textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/dasdasd">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
    android:id="@+id/thisIsTheTextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:textAppearance="?    
    android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
```

finally in your `Activity`

```
ArrayAdapter myAD=new ArrayAdapter(mContext,R.layout.myLayout,R.id.thisIsTheTextView,new String[] {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"});
myListView.setAdapter(myAD);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the response, but which part does that last snippet of code replace?

Comment: you can add it to the `onCreate()` to populate the ListView.. This is after you `setContentView(R.layout.main)` I gave you all the codes